# How to get the last character of a string?

Tags: javascript

How to get the last character of the string:

```
"linto.yahoo.com."
```

The last character of this string is `"."`

How can I find this?

Comment: function getLastCharacter(name) {
    return name.substr(-1)

}
console.log(getLastCharacter("Sam")); // "m"

Answer (score 1425):

An elegant and short alternative, is the [`String.prototype.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) method.

Just by:

```
str.slice(-1);
```

A negative start index slices the string from `length+index`, to `length`, being index `-1`, the last character is extracted:

```
"abc".slice(-1); // "c";
```

Comment: Side note: arrays also have a [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) method. - Their functionality is conceptually similar (partial copies) -------- (Just in case you're reading code and see `.slice()`)

Comment: What do you mean by a "UTF-8 string"?  The phrase makes no sense.  FWIW though, JavaScript strings are funny beasts themselves: they are sequences of unsigned 16-bit integer values.  If the intent of your string is to store characters, then the code above returns the last 16-bit value, which would not be pretty if it was the second part of a surrogate pair.  But again, what exactly do you mean by "UTF-8 string"?  UTF-8 is an encoding scheme that might make sense if you had a byte array, but means nothing at all when it comes to strings.  Just curious.

Comment: @Egg, seems that you didn't try my example, `str.slice(-1)` does indeed get the last character of the string (as the OP required), just as if you used `str.charAt(str.length - 1)`, try: `"abc".slice(-1)`. I was showing here a usage of `String.prototype.slice` with a negative index. `str.slice(-n)` will get the last `n` characters of the original string as a new string value. More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice

Comment: @CMS You are right, your method does actually grab the last char of the string without trimming it. Nice elegant method too. For some reason I was thinking it was going to trim those chars and return a trimmed string. Sorry about that, I feel like an idiot for not trying it first.

Comment: Well, How can I get the position of lase character? `"abc "` Now I need to get `4` *(there is a space in the end)*, How can I do that?

Comment: This code may be short and "sexy" but I won't use it. The code is not self explanatory and not clear. Use charAt instead.

Comment: @stack The position (counting from 1) of the last character should be the length of a string, basically `.length` I'm not sure how it handles surrogate pairs.

Comment: −1 is the only index for which this works, though; it doesn’t generalize well to n-th from the end.

Answer (score 136):

Use [`charAt`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_charAt.asp):

> The charAt() method returns the character at the specified index in a string.

You can use this method in conjunction with the [`length`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_length_string.asp) property of a string to get the last character in that string.
For example:

```js
const myString = "linto.yahoo.com.";
const stringLength = myString.length; // this will be 16
console.log('lastChar: ', myString.charAt(stringLength - 1)); // this will be the string
```

Answer (score 104):

You can achieve this using different ways but with different performance,

**1. Using bracket notation:**

`var str = "Test";
  var lastLetter = str[str.length - 1];`

But it's not recommended to use brackets. Check the reasons [here](http://blog.vjeux.com/2009/javascript/dangerous-bracket-notation-for-strings.html)

**2. charAt[index]:**

`var lastLetter = str.charAt(str.length - 1)`

**This is readable and fastest among others. It is most recommended way.**

**3. substring:**

`str.substring(str.length - 1);`

**4. slice:**

`str.slice(-1);`

It's slightly faster than substring.

You can check the performance [here](https://jsperf.com/charat-vs-index/5)

**With ES6:**

You can use `str.endsWith("t");`

But it is not supported in IE. Check more details about endsWith [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith)

Comment: No need to do performance squeezing on current machines. Use the most concise solution. My vote is on `str.slice(-1);`

Comment: I'm not sure how `endsWith` fits here, that does something completely different.

Comment: Re: bracket notation(BN)

1/ This is 2022, screw IE7.
2/ Coders trying to `put` chars with BN shouldn't be coding.

Answer (score 81):

```
str.charAt(str.length - 1)
```

Some browsers allow (as a non-standard extension) you to shorten this to:

```
str[str.length - 1];
```

Comment: Outdated answer. Using bracket notation is not a non-standard extension.

Answer (score 41):

Use [substr](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp) with parameter **-1**:

> "linto.yahoo.com.".substr(-1);

equals "."

Note:

> To extract characters from the end of the string, use a negative start number (This does not work in IE 8 and earlier).

Comment: Seems like this one is as shorter as slice(), I wonder wich one is better and faster.

Comment: substr is a legacy feature and is optional outside of web browsers. slice is better.

Answer (score 29):

Using the `String.prototype.at()` method is a new way to achieve it

```js
const s = "linto.yahoo.com.";
const last = s.at(-1);

console.log(last);
```

Read more about [at](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/at)

Answer (score 12):

Try this...

```
const str = "linto.yahoo.com."
console.log(str.charAt(str.length-1));
```

Answer (score 10):

You can get the last char like this :

```
var lastChar=yourString.charAt(yourString.length-1);
```

Answer (score 7):

```
var firstName = "Ada";
var lastLetterOfFirstName = firstName[firstName.length - 1];
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 5):

Use the JavaScript [charAt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/global_objects/string/charat) function to get a character at a given 0-indexed position. Use [length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length) to find out how long the String is. You want the last character so that's length - 1. 
Example:

```
var word = "linto.yahoo.com.";
var last = word.charAt(word.length - 1);
alert('The last character is:' + last);
```

Answer (score 5):

If you have or are already using lodash, use [last](https://lodash.com/docs/latest#last) instead:

```
_.last(str);
```

Not only is it more concise and obvious than the vanilla JS, it also safer since it avoids `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property X of undefined` when the input is `null` or `undefined` so you don't need to check this beforehand:

```js
// Will throw Uncaught TypeError if str is null or undefined
str.slice(-1); 
str.charAt(str.length -1);

// Returns undefined when str is null or undefined
_.last(str);
```

Comment: It's important to note that this could cause you to run into other issues, such as expecting it to return a string when it really returns undefined. This could be useful in some cases but in general it's probably better to just use `try...catch`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following. In this case of last character it's an overkill but for a substring, its useful:

```
var word = "linto.yahoo.com.";
var last = ".com.";
if (word.substr(-(last.length)) == last)
alert("its a match");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify using .at(-1)

```
let string = "linto.yahoo.com."
console.log(string.at(-1)
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use this simple ES6 method

```js
const lastChar = (str) => str.split('').reverse().join(',').replace(',', '')[str.length === str.length + 1 ? 1 : 0];


// example
console.log(lastChar("linto.yahoo.com."));
```

This will work in every browsers.

Comment: it won't work if the original string had commas in it -1

Comment: It's sooo complicated. If you want to convert it to an array and reverse it, why not just `(str) => str.split('').reverse()[0]`? :)

Comment: Some people do not understand second degree

Comment: This is hilarious, thanks vdegenne! Obviously the slice(-1) answer with all the upvotes is the best one, but this one does put me in mind of a relatively terse alternative that nobody else seems to have suggested: `const lastChar=str.split('').pop()`