# Extract sub string from last in a string JS

Tags: javascript

I need to write JS function which returns true if string contains `- depreciated` in its last otherwise false.

For example:

```
var somestring = "string value - depreciated";
```

function should return true in above example.

```
function isDepreciated(var S)
{
    //Need to check for substring in last
    //return true or false
}
```

One possible solution is to use `search` function but that means that if `- depreciated` comes within string then it will also return true. I really need to find weather substring is in last or not.

Please help.

Comment: Homework? What have you tried?

Comment: Learn about `match` and `RegExp` and try them out.

Comment: You could also do this by using [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) to isolate the last X characters of the input and see if they match what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use the Javascript string method `.substr()` combined with the `.length` property.

```
function isDepreciated(var id)
{
    var id = "string value - depreciated";
    var lastdepreciated = id.substr(id.length - 13); // => "- depreciated"
    //return true or false check for true or flase
}
```

This gets the characters starting at id.length - 13 and, since the second argument for .substr() is omitted, continues to the end of the string.

Comment: Does negative indexing supported in IE versions below or equal to 8?

Comment: @NidaSulheri yes u can ... kindly check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6918943/substr-with-negative-value-not-working-in-ie

Answer (score 2):

Add the below code in your JS

```
function isDepreciated(string){
   return  /(-depreciated)$/.test(string);
}
```

Comment: A regular expression is not necessary.

Comment: Also, should probably escape the `-`, though it's not necessarily required.

Comment: Yeah! It might not be, but I find this is the shortest and robust line of code to solve this problem.

Comment: @Jack why not necessary?

Comment: @meze I've marked this question as a duplicate of a more generic problem; you can find the solution there as well, or look at Marginean Vlad's answer.

Comment: @Jack that doesn't explain why not regexp. It takes less characters and probably will be faster.

Comment: @meze I prefer finding simple functions that solve the exact problem first before moving to regular expressions as an alternative to string domain problems. This has nothing to do with speed; if it did, you'd probably be wrong though :)

Answer (score 1):

```
function isDepreciated(S) {
    var suffix = "- depreciated";
    return S.indexOf(suffix, S.length - suffix.length) !== -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use currying: http://ejohn.org/blog/partial-functions-in-javascript/

```
Function.prototype.curry = function() {
    var fn = this, args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    return function() {
      return fn.apply(this, args.concat(
        Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
    };
  };
```

With the helper curry function you could create your isDepricated check:

```
String.prototype.isDepricated = String.prototype.match.curry(/- depreciated$/);

"string value - depreciated".isDepricated();
```

---

Or use `.bind()`:

```
var isDepricated = RegExp.prototype.test.bind(/- depreciated$/);

isDepricated("string value - depreciated");
```

Comment: The problem being solved is more specific, so I wouldn't modify the String prototype for that.

Comment: You are probably right so I added a `bind` example ;)

Comment: I see you're an avid fan of the JavaScript dynamism ;-) +1 for the creative aspect hehe

Answer (score 0):

```
function isDepreciated(S){
    return (new RegExp(" - depriciated$").test(S));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

how about just use regular expression

```
  var myRe=/depreciated$/;
  var myval = "string value - depreciated";
  if (myRe.exec(myval)) {
    alert ('found');
  }
  else{
    alert('not found');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

lots of answers are already here (the one with $ is preferred), even though i also had to write one, so it will also do your job,

```
var somestring = "string value - depreciated";
var pattern="- depreciated";

function isDepreciated(var s)
{
    b=s.substring(s.length-pattern.length,s.length)==pattern;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I haven't run this code on a browser, but this should give a basic idea of what to do. You might have to tweak some of the conditions if needed.

```
var search = "- depricated";
var pos = str.indexOf(search);

if(pos > 0 && pos + search.length == str.length){
    return true;
}
else{
   return false;
}
```

Edit: `indexOf()` returns the start index of the string.

Comment: pos > 0, so that the string should be found and the next condition to see whether it is located at the end. A cleaner approach would be to do regex as posted by @Avneesh Raghav.

Comment: `contains` returns boolean and isn't supported in all browsers ;(

Comment: Edited to indexOf(), thanks for spotting that.

Comment: Why the `if (foo) return true; else return false;` Why not just return the evaluation of the condition (`return foo;`)? A nitpick, but it seems rather redundant.

Comment: Since the OP seems to be a student, I thought it would be easier to understand.

Answer (score -1):

```
    function isDeprecated(str) {
          return ((str.indexOf("- depreciated") == str.length - "- depreciated".length) ? true : false);
    }

    isDeprecated("this")
    false

    isDeprecated("this - depreciated")
    true

    isDeprecated("this - depreciated abc")
    false
```