# string array output with numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, output

I don't have any experience with javascript and I have a basic question about arrays. I can't seem to find it on the internet.

I'm using a basic array like this:

```
var names = new Array('Jorn', 'Janine', 'Peter', 'Magchiel', 'Marieke', 'Pieter');
```

The output needs to be something like this:

```
[0] = Jorn, [1] = Janine, [2] = Peter, ...
```

And so on. I'm really struggling with this.

I hope someone could help me with this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you need the output for, is the question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That should work, iterate over keys "foreach-like" and get their values :

```
var names = new Array('Jorn', 'Janine', 'Peter', 'Magchiel', 'Marieke', 'Pieter');
var result = '';
for(var i in names){
    result += '[' + i + '] = ' + names[i] + ', ';
}
alert(result);
```

Comment: Thanks alot! This worked, I knew it was something with a foreach but I didn't know how to use it.

Comment: Actually that's a bad solution. Using `for .. in` with arrays is wrong. Use a proper `for` loop like in ElliotM's answer.

Comment: It's a bad idea only if you rewrite array prototype, and even then you can use something like `names.hasOwnProperty(i)` to make sure it's an actual array element. Or did you think of something else ?

Answer (score 1):

This basically builds a string for output via a `for-loop`, then tells the windows to output the raw string.

```
var output="";
for(var i=0;i<names.length;i++){
output+="[" + i + "]" + " = " + names[i] + ", ";
}
output=output.slice(0,-2);
document.write(output);
```

Comment: use `str.slice(0,-1);` to remove last char, [not substring with negative values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6918943/substr-with-negative-value-not-working-in-ie), but I think you want the last 2 chars (not only 1). On a side note, I do use substring to remove first char like `str.substring(1);`

Comment: actually, my mistake, you weren't using negative values, but anyway, the new way is shorter and works one IE6+

Comment: I usually use slice, not sure why I originally went w/ substring :S