# Replacing hash with a string in the first n-characters of a url hash

Tags: javascript, url, hash

I have a `$location.path()` that is of the following type of format:

```
/request/add/c3smsVdMHpVvSrspy8Vwrr5Zh8qSyP7q
```

I am interested in filtering the hash after `/request/add/` to the following. As you can see, the last four chars are shown, but everything else before that is labeled as `[FILTERED]`

```
/request/add/[FILTERED]yP7q
```

I did some basic code which converts the hidden chars to `#`, but I got stuck in trying to apply the string `[FILTERED]` *after* the `/request/add`.

```
old_path = $location.path()
path = old_path.replace(/.(?=.{4,}$)/g, '#');
```

Comment: It appears you're using AngularJS 1.x or Angular 2. The answer will depend on what you're using for routing, likely.

Comment: can you use .split('/') and then put it into a new var?

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873810/how-can-i-get-last-characters-of-a-string-using-javascript

Comment: @Darkrum how is it a duplicate of that if that just teaches me how to use a substring which isn't the complete point of this question?

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring). This will give you the `[FILTERED]` contents then you can do whatever you'd like with them.

```js
var old_path = '/request/add/c3smsVdMHpVvSrspy8Vwrr5Zh8qSyP7q';
var filtered = old_path.substring('/request/add/'.length, old_path.length - 4);
var path = old_path.replace(filtered, '[FILTERED]');
console.log(path);
```

Comment: This only substrings out that first n-characters, and doesn't replace it with `[FILTERED]`. I would accept your answer if you did that.

Comment: @theGreenCabbage Edited. It's just a matter of replacing what you've extracted with what you actually want.

Comment: This is perfect, thanks. I actually have a set of paths like `/request/add/` that I would love the method to rotate through to see if there is a match. For example `/request/remove/`, `/request/update/`, etc. What's the cleanest way to do this?

Comment: @theGreenCabbage That all depends on what you're trying to match. This doesn't "match" anything, it just replaces a section of a string.

Comment: The match is just a string match like from the examples I listed. Nothing too fancy.

Comment: @theGreenCabbage So you want to see if the path ends in some kind of hash? Or that it's been filtered? Your examples aren't really matching anything either... Unless you're saying the path could start with `/request/add/`, `/request/remove/` etc. Then that's totally doable.