# Javascript: Getting last few characters of a string

Tags: javascript, string

This is a trivial problem if we are storing string in a variable. But out of curiosity, I need to understand how to achieve this without storing string in variable?

```
//  To get first few characters of a string, we can do something like this:
var x = "amangupta".substring(0,7); //amangup

//  How to get last 7 characters
var x = "amangupta".substring(this.length - 7, this.length); // does not work, looking for similar approach

var str = "amangupta";
var x = str.substring(str.length - 7, str.length); // will work fine
```

Comment: This is a duplicate question please go to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/15473635/5452965

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> How to get last 7 characters

Try

```
"amangupta".slice(-7)
```

Answer (score 0):

Without an extra variable you need to use the string again

```
"amangupta".substring("amangupta".length - 7, "amangupta".length);
```

Comment: "amangupta" is a random string getting generated from some function, which I should have included in my question.