# In POSTMAN how do i get substring of response header item?

Tags: postman, postman-pre-request-script

I am using postman to get response header value like below:

```
var data = postman.getResponseHeader("Location") . //value is "http://aaa/bbb" for example
```

I can print the value via `console.log(data)` easily.

However, what I really want is "bbb". So I need some `substring()` type of function. And apparently 'data' is not a javascript string type, because `data.substring(10)` for example always return null.

Does anyone what i need to do in this case?

If any postman API doc existing that explains this?

Comment: is that exact error what you get?

Comment: actually only toString() is needed firstly to convert it to javascript string, then it's self explanatory.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get last characters of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873810/how-can-i-get-last-characters-of-a-string)

Answer (score 3):

You have the full flexibility of JavaScript at your fingertips here, so just split the String and use the part after the last `/`:

```
var data = pm.response.headers.get("Location").split("/").pop());
```

See W3 school's documentation of [split](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) and [pop](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_pop.asp) if you need more in depth examples of JavaScript internals.

Comment: This is the way...

Answer (score 2):

You can set an environment variable in postman. try something like

```
var data = JSON.parse(postman.getResponseHeader("Location"));
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("dataObj", data.href.substring(10));
```

Comment: no, that's not the solution, i saw same solution somewhere else in SO. my header is not returning a json object.

Comment: for my specific needs that worked, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Some initial thought - I needed a specific part of the "Location" header like the OP, but I had to also get a specific value from that specific part.
My header would look something like this

*https://example.com?code_challenge_method=S256&redirect_uri=https://localhost:8080&response_type=code&state=vi8qPxcvv7I&nonce=uq95j99qBCGgJvrHjGoFtJiBoo*

And I need the "state" value to pass on to the next request as a variable

```
var location_header = pm.response.headers.get("Location");
var attributes = location_header.split('&');

console.log(attributes);

var len = attributes.length;
var state_attribute_value = ""
var j = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    attribute_key = attributes[i].split('=')[0];
    if (attribute_key == "state") {
        state_attribute_value = attributes[i].split('=')[1];
    }
    j = j + 1;
}
console.log(state_attribute_value);
pm.environment.set("state", state_attribute_value);
```

Might you get the point here, "split" is the choice to give you some array of values. 
If the text you are splitting is always giving the same array length it should be easy to catch the correct number