# on input get only new input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a text input where I get the input and use it. I have:

```
$(myinput).on('input', function() {
 $(somediv).append($(this).val());
});
```

I would like to keep using the append function, but the problem is on every input, the entire input val() is being appended. So when I click 'a', its adding 'a', but when I click 'b' after a, it appends 'ab' not 'b'.

is there a way to only get the input of the most recent .input event without clearing out the input box?

Comment: I would like to keep using the append function? why?

Comment: You want to use `.append`, but you don't want to append?

Comment: @codehx I was using `$(somediv).text();` instead of append, but that was screwing up some other html I had inside the div

Comment: Then put an element with id ( say `<span id = "replaceable"></span>`) for the replaceable content. Then you freely use `$("#replaceable").text("your text")`, if you want to do it this way I can post an answer.

Comment: @codehx yea I guess that works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use `.text()` instead of `.append()`. This will set the whole text, not just append it.

`$(somediv).text($(this).val());`

Or you could use the last char of your string.

`$(somediv).text($(this).val().slice(-1));`
See: [how to get the last character of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3884632/how-to-get-the-last-character-of-a-string)

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you want to use `append` because there is other content in `somediv` that you don't want to lose.  If that is the case, you can create a sub-element to receive the text, append it just once, then change its contents when the `input` field changes:

```
var receiver = $('span');
$(somediv).append(receiver);

$(myinput).on('input', function() {
 receiver.html($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#myinput").on('input', function() {
   $("#somewhere").val("");
   setTimout(function() {
       $("#somewhere").append($(this).val());
   },10);
});
```

or

```
$("#myinput").focusout(function() {
   $("#somewhere").val("");
   setTimout(function() {
       $("#somewhere").append($(this).val());
   },10);
});
```

the timeout is for doing things without overlapping.
You can try also without timoeout

Answer (score 0):

You could also bind to the `keyup` event:

```
$(document).on('keyup', '#inputID', function(e){
     var key = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
    $('div').append(key);
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6psyjhqp/)