# How to manipulate the characters written in a div to work with them afterwards using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
function doGetWord(){
            var word = F.gword.value;
            var wLength = word.length;
            for(var i = 0; i < wLength; i++){
                document.getElementById("dword").innerHTML += "_ "  
            }
        }
```

This is a function that will write _ in a div in html, and what I want is to change them if the user types the corresponding input, for example if the first letter is supposed to be "a" then it would change the first _ to "a".

This is what I got so far:

```
function doGuessWord(){
            dummy = F.t.value
            if(dummy.length > 1){
                dummy = ""
                F.t.value = ""
            }
            for(var x = 0; x < wLength; x++){
                if (substr(x, wLength) == dummy ) {
                    document.getElementById("dword").innerHTML += "_ "      
                }
                else{
                    document.getElementById("dword").innerHTML += "dummy "  
                }
            }
        }
```

Could you help me out with this one?
Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: How are you getting the word? From an `input` element?

Comment: Yeah the user types the word in the input.

Comment: Put the number of `_` s into an array, then keep adding the last user inputted character on `keyup` event, to another array. Then having an incrementer variable somewhere in the code change the value of the array with the `_`s to the other one. Example dashArr[i] = charArr[i]. Then you'd need to write the content of the dashArr to the document again.

Comment: If you're still lost I could write a simple fiddle quick

Comment: Hmm I kinda understood what you said, but what's the keyup event? A fiddle would be awesome if you have some time.

Comment: Writing it now. There are a couple of events like this. `Keydown`, `keypress`, and `keyup` are the ones you could use in this case. I recommend reading about them. The difference is simple but makes a big difference.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vhsf8gpp/1/ This is pretty close. I'll work on leaving the dashes

Comment: What I really wanted was something like an input where the user would choose a word and then the other one could guess a letter and if it is in the word it would replace the "_" thing.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

https://jsfiddle.net/9z66968a/3/

You will have to adapt it a bit. But you should be able to take the `parseText` function and pass it the params you need to return the text to insert where ever you want

Comment: hmm, could you explain your code a little bit? I've never used such terms :/ xD

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9z66968a/4/ I updated the code and added comments. let me know if that is more clear.

Comment: What I really wanted was something like an input where the user would choose a word and then the other one could guess a letter and if it is in the word it would replace the "_" thing.

Comment: You can use that function I wrote however you like. I don't know exactly what you want to do. Plus it sounds like you're learning so it wouldn't do any good to do the whole thing for you anyway

Answer (score 0):

There you go. I believe this is what you wanted. Feel free if you don't understand something
https://jsfiddle.net/vhsf8gpp/2/

```
var dashArr = [];
var dummyWord = document.getElementById('dummy');
var input = document.querySelector('input');
var counter = 0;

for(let i= 0; i<10;i++)
{
  dashArr.push('_');
}

function WriteContent()
{
  dummyWord.textContent = dashArr.map(d=>d).join(''); // This gets rid of the ',' inbetween the dashes
}

WriteContent();
//var charArr = [];
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('keyup',function(){
  var inputString = input.value;
  dashArr[counter] = inputString.charAt(inputString.length - 1);
  WriteContent();
  counter++;
})
```

I used  [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3884632/how-to-get-the-last-character-of-a-string) for reference.

Comment: What I really wanted was something like an input where the user would choose a word and then the other one could guess a letter and if it is in the word it would replace the "_" thing.

Comment: So you just need one if statement? And change it only if it's the right word?

Comment: Right letter* and yes xD

Comment: How is it different from what e-e made?