# Get currency symbol from a string price

Tags: javascript

I have a prices:

```
var str1 = '10,00 €';
var str2 = '12.22 $';
```

I need get only currency symbol. I writed function:

```
 function stringToCurrency(str){
    return Number(str.replace("€", "").replace("$", "");
}
```

But this only replace currency symbol on `''`. How I can get currency symbol?

Comment: Your function wouldn't work. You have a syntax error as there's a bracket missing.

Comment: @deceze He is not explicitly asking how to get the last character. You are making the assumption that the currency symbol will always be the last character, which is certainly not the case in all localizations.

Comment: *I need get only currency symbol*......why you are converting that to number?

Comment: @devios1 From the sample data given, yes, I am assuming that. So does every answer so far. If that is not the case, the question needs to be clarified.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get the last character of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3884632/how-to-get-the-last-character-of-a-string)

Comment: @deceze But assuming it to the point of *closing the question*? Having a bad day are we? A proper solution to the question as stated would make no such assumption. You're only looking at two data points.

Comment: @devios1 Nope, pretty regular day as far as that goes around here. If you want to attempt to answer a vague question based on two data points, be my guest…

Comment: @deceze I was about to, but then the question was closed! Fortunately Chris Barr basically said what I was going to, which by the way makes no assumptions about the position of the currency symbol in the string.

Answer (score 8):

If we use a regex to remove everything else (numbers, periods, commas, spaces) then we are only left with the currency symbols

```js
var str1 = '10,00 €';
var str2 = '12.22 $';

function getCurrencySymbol(str) {
  //replace all numbers, spaces, commas, and periods with an empty string
  //we should only be left with the currency symbols
  return str.replace(/[\d\., ]/g, '');
}

console.log(getCurrencySymbol(str1));
console.log(getCurrencySymbol(str2));
```

Comment: Sure, but commas, periods, spaces are also non-numeric and those would also be returned

Comment: Instead of replacing you can use a negated character set to find the currency symbol: `/[^\d\.,\s]*/g` but it achieves the same result.

Comment: ***on side note:-*** You don't need to escape `.` inside character class, anyways good one +1

Answer (score 0):

Just pick the last char of the string

```
function stringToCurrency(str) {
    return str.trim().charAt(str.length - 1);
}
```

Comment: I'd prefer doing trim before substr. That empty space has caused me enough trouble

Comment: You shoud use `substring`; `substr` is obsolete.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply write a function that returns the last character of the string which represents the symbol that you want. Since Javascript string is a char array, you can access the last character by the length of the string as follows.

```
function stringToCurrency(str){
    return str[str.length-1];
}
```

Hope It will help you! Thanks

Comment: You can use `.charAt` instead; [it has better support](http://blog.vjeux.com/2009/javascript/dangerous-bracket-notation-for-strings.html).

Answer (score -2):

The way `Number()` works, is it returns an integer given any set of data. When you're passing these variables into it, like `'10,00 €'`, the `Number` function will return NaN because you're passing symbols and spaces into it.

To return only the symbol, JS has built-in methods that can be chained on to easily deal with this.

If the location is known, but value not, we can return the value of the given string location with `charAt()`

```
function knownLocation(s) {
  return s.charAt(s.length -1)
}
```

If the location of that symbol is **unknown**, but you know it's there, we can check which is there with `.includes` and then return the character at the index.

```
function knownValue(s) {
 if (s.includes("$")) {
    return s.charAt(s.indexOf("$"))
 } else if (s.includes("€")) {
   return s.charAt(s.indexOf("€"))
 } else {
   return undefined
 }
}
```

Comment: Uhm… `if (s.includes('$')) return '$';`…

Comment: @deceze Haha! Didn't see that at all