# How can I get the last character/number in input fields?

Tags: javascript, html, python-3.x

How to call the input id in javascript using the python class base views?

Javascript:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var txt = document.getElementById("Plate_no").value;
  var res = txt.charAt(txt.length-1);
  document.getElementById("Ending").innerHTML = res;
}
</script
```

And this is my HTML form

```
<form method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <label>Plate Number:</label>{{ form.Plate_no }}
        <button onclick="myFunction()">Get Ending</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <label>Conduction Sticker Number:</label>{{ form.Conduction_Sticker }}
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <label>Remarks:</label>{{ form.Remarks }}
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <label>CR Name:</label>{{ form.CR_name }}
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <label >Ending:</label>{{ form.Ending }}
    </div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3884632/how-to-get-the-last-character-of-a-string/3884711#3884711)

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript a string is a char array, hence you can access the last character by the length of the string.

```
var res = txt[txt.length -1];
```

Comment: Yes, but in my javascript code can't get the input value. It is possible to call the fields since I'm using a class base views?

Comment: Assuming you have a proper ID called Plate_no, you can try to instead use `innerText`, like so 
`var txt =document.getElementById("Plate_no").innerText`. That might work.

Answer (score 0):

When using the `getElementById()` function, you need to have an `id=""` attribute on the element you want to select.

```html
<label> Plate Number: </label>
<span id="plate_no"> {{ form.Plate_no }} </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var txt = document.querySelectorAll("input")[0].value;
  var res = txt.charAt(txt.length-1);
  document.getElementById("Ending").innerHTML = res;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <label>Plate Number:</label><input>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Get Ending</button>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <label>Conduction Sticker Number:</label>{{ form.Conduction_Sticker }}
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <label>Remarks:</label>{{ form.Remarks }}
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <label>CR Name:</label>{{ form.CR_name }}
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <label >Ending:</label><div id="Ending">{{ form.Ending }}</div>
</div>
```